# React-Bootstrap OverlayTrigger not working when overlay is something other than a ToolTip or Popover

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

The documentation for the react-bootstrap overlay trigger says that the overlay prop can be an element or text.  However, whenever I pass it something other than a "Tooltip" component it doesn't work.  In fact, if you modify their code example on the website linked below to be just a div instead of a Tooltip or a string, it doesn't work on their site either.  Does it have to be passed a Tooltip?

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips-overlay-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to pass is a `Tooltip` or a `Popover`.

You could also pass it something else, but then you have to wrap it in an `Overlay` instead of an `OverlayTrigger`. See the react-bootstrap docs on [Custom Overlays](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-overlays) for more specific examples.

Comment: Thanks Danny.  However, I'm talking about what can be passed to OverlayTrigger which means I wouldn't want to wrap it in an overlay.  Their documentation for the overlay prop says "An element or text to overlay next to the target.", but I don't think "text" is accurate.  Looks to me like it has to be a Tooltip or Popover or some other element of that nature.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a CSS issue where they have custom CSS for Popovers and OverlayTriggers for the placement of the overlay and I just need my own custom CSS for whatever element I decide to use?